# Maven goal "war:inplace" generates webapp folder for non-war projects

Tags: java, maven

I set up a maven multi module project, one with packaging "war" two more with packaging "jar".

When I execute "mvn war:inplace" on the parent project, Maven generates a folder src/main/webapp for every subproject. In my understanding, it only makes sense for the WAR-projects. How can I tell Maven not to run that goal on the JAR projects?

Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you defined the maven-war-plugin in your root pom ?

Comment: No, i haven't. Why is that necessary? What exactly do i specify there?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the mvn war:inplace not from the root of your mulit-module build. The simple solution is to cd into the war module and do it there. 
Or you can use/try the following. Go into the root folder and try:

```
mvn -pl YourWarModuleName war:inplace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use executions element in pom.xml war plugin for the web-apps in your multi-module project.

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>war-inplace</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>inplace</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```